# Spring Core as Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a Spring Boot project with entities, repositories, services, and rest controllers. It all works, but my mentor gave me a task where I must start my application without @SpringBootApplication.

So how can I achieve it without creating webapp, xml and especially any html files?

In other words, how can I replace the annotation with f.ex. Java custom(or not) classes?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? You should clarify which application you need to start.

Comment: Are you still allowed to use Spring Boot without `@SpringBootApplication`?

Comment: I have a simple Spring Boot application which has different endpoints, but right now I need to run my project so that I can call my endpoints, but without using @SpringBootApplication at all. No, I'm not allowed to use Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

Annotation `SpringBootApplication` is a enterence for convenient load into spring context , it located at `spring-boot-auto-configure-starter` package , In general , the `SpringBootApplication` would automaticcally inject the bean which  is required , such as web application scenario , it would  inject network context like tomcat , netty ,Datasourcebean like oracle , mysql ,pgsql .

In a nutshell  , if you would like to  get the compact spring context  you read the following code snippet

```java
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        // previous applicationContext.xml is your bean Definition scope  or else you can use AnnotationContext 
         // ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

        // Your Spring context is now initialized.
        // You can access beans and use them.
    }
}
```

more about spring ioc container click here [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your class with
@ComponentScan and
@EnableAutoConfiguration and try the following method to run you application

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(YourApp.class);
    app.run();
}
```